# Java generic type of a generic type

Tags: java, generics

How do I something like this in Java

```
 class TreeNode<Item<K,V>> {

}
```

The code above does not compile.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? Depending on what you are trying to do, what you are requesting may be known as higher kinded types, which Java does not support. But it's hard to say from your current wording.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare `K` and `V` to be generic parameters and you have to declare the name of the type parameter you want bound to `Item<K, V>`. Assuming that `Item` is a predefined generic type, you can do something like this, for instance:

```
class TreeNode<K, V, X extends Item<K, V>> {
    ...
}
```

Or perhaps (and more likely) you don't need a separate type parameter `X` and just need to declare `K` and `V` as type parameters:

```
class TreeNode<K, V> {
    private Item<K, V> mItem;
    ...
}
```